# Visual Studio 2022 sometimes shows "The application was unable to start correctly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a console program in .NET 6 on Visual Studio 2022. Sometimes, when I start debugging, instead of starting the program it shows `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.` If I close and reopen VS, it lets me start debugging again (at least for a while, until this message starts showing again). Any thoughts on why and if there is a way to fix it without have to close and reopen VS?

Comment: New shiny bugs are shiny

Comment: If you have a problem, report it to Microsoft so that it might get fixed.

Comment: I found there is a [fix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/%E9%BB%98%E8%AE%A4%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8Terminal%E6%97%B6%EF%BC%8C%E8%B0%83%E8%AF%95%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E4%B8%8D%E8%83%BD%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E5%85%B3%E9%97%AD%EF%BC%8C%E5%90%A6%E5%88%99%E4%B8%8B%E4%B8%80%E6%AC%A1%E5%90%AF%E5%8A%A8%E6%97%B6%E4%BC%9A%E6%98%BE%E7%A4%BA%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E6%89%93%E5%BC%80/1576610) for this bug. You may upgrade your Visual Studio to check if this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio 2022 bug when you use Terminal as a default console.
If you close the opened console window while it's in a Console.ReadLine it crashes the program, and you can't open another instance for debugging unless you close and reopen vs.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll be sure to avoid that then.